# SQL query that will generate child_id recursively

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have the following table structure:

```
ORGANIZATION_ID   | Name  |  PARENT_ID
--------------------------------------------------
1                 | A     |     0   -Indicates root
2                 | B     |     1
3                 | C     |     2
4                 | D     |     2
5                 | E     |     4
6                 | F     |     1
7                 | G     |     1
8                 | H     |     7
9                 | J     |     8
10                | K     |     9
```

I am not that great at writing Oracle SQL queries. How can I generate a list of everything (`*`) child organisation if I pass in a certain Organization ID?

For instance, if I passed in `2`, logically I would look for all rows who had a parent ID of 2, then I would recursively look through each of those rows doing the same thing.

I know the logic, how can I recreate that using a sql query in oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CONNECT BY`](http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html) can be used to make this recursive query:

```
SELECT organization_id, name
FROM t
CONNECT BY PRIOR organization_id = parent_id
START WITH organization_id = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Oracle 11g, Oracle recursive subquery is alternative.

```
with orgs (organization_id, name, parent_id) as (
    select organization_id, name, parent_id 
        from organization
        where organization_id=2
    union all
        select organization_id, name, parent_id 
        from organization org join orgs on org.parent_id=orgs.organization_id)
search depth first by organization_id set a
select organization_id, name
from orgs;
```